# Connected a Mobile device (Android) as MTP, Now can we access this device and get Time

Tags: java, android, mtp

I am trying to develop an application in which I am connecting my mobile device to a Computer as a MTP.
Now I am trying to access this MTP from my java code using some external library.
My requirement is to get time from that device and calculate offset on the Computer.
But I am not able to do the same.
Can we do something like this.

I tried doing this using USB tethering and creating two way socket communication but this will require opening of sockets and will make application less secure.

Comment: Is there anybody who tried these kind of things.?

Comment: read about MTP....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if USB debugging is enabled on that device then you can access device status using `ADB` command in CMD.